# Incorrect resolution and screen tearing

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, display-resolution, intel, tearing

I must say right away that I don't speak English well. I apologize for possible errors and misunderstandings. 
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on Huawei MateBook 13. 
I can't solve the problem with incorrect resolution display and tearing in any way. 
I'll get to the point:

```
$ neofetch

...
Resolution: 3456x2304 
...
CPU: Intel i5-8265U (8) @ 3.900GH
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX250
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
...
```

But the resolution of my screen is 2160x1440. The same thing when running xrandr:

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3456 x 2304, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 3456x2304+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 275mm x 183mm
   2160x1440     60.00*+
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It seems to me that the system incorrectly perceives the resolution of my screen, as a result of which the Intel GPU can not cope with render such a picture, as a result of which there is tearing.
I would be happy to use only NVIDIA GPU, but when I use only NVIDIA, the battery runs out very quickly.
For a complete understanding, tearing is about like [this](https://iwf1.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Nvidia-tearing.jpg).
This happens when dragging windows, watching videos, and even when scrolling through web pages.
Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. I will be glad of your help.

Comment: What resolutions are available in display settings / system settings?

Answer (score 1):

In your Nvidia X Server Setting follow these steps -

1. Navigate to X Server Display Configuration
2. You can change your resolution here
3. Click on Adavanced settings
4. Select "Force Composition Pipeline"  // This will fix screen tearing
5. Select "Force Full Compostion Pipeline" // Try both and select what works best for you
6. Apply and save your configuration